# Why is setAttribute not working in Javascript with SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg, transform

I'm a beginner with SVG and Javascript and would be glad if someone could help me. Does anyone have an idea why with this Code in SVG and Javascript

```
<g id="package1">

  <rect style="opacity:1;fill:#00b609;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:0;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" id="rect991" width="1.6536481" height="11.641669" x="145.52083" y="28.447916" />

</g>

<script type="text/javascript" id="move">
  var package1 = document.getElementById("package1");

  package1.setAttribute("transform", "translate(210,120) rotate(-10 50 100)");
</script>
```

nothing happens to the rectangular even though it should be rotated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It does something. You need to put your `rect` inside `svg` element.

```js
  setTimeout(() => {
    var package1 = document.getElementById("package1");

   package1.setAttribute("transform", "translate(210,120) rotate(-10 50 100)"); 
   }, 2000);
```

```css
#package1 {
  border: 1pt solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg id="package1">

  <rect style="opacity:1;fill:#00b609;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:1;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" id="rect991" width="10.6536481" height="110.641669" x="145.52083" y="28.447916" />

</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, now I know the code itself is working.

I did put the rect plus the Javascript-Code inside an svg element, I'll try to find out what's wrong.

Comment: I had more code in the script-section which I removed, now it's working! Thanks!

Comment: @ppp Great. Happy to help. If you are satisfied, please vote for the answer.